# Improper Neutralization of Special Elements in Data Query Logic for Mongoose Create in Veracode

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, veracode

I am using mongoose create function to add to my collection. I am taking data from request body and passing it to create function like this -

```
const someVariable = req.body;

await userModelName.create(someVariable);
```

On `veracode`, it showing Improper Neutralization of Special Elements in Data Query Logic for this statement - `await userModelName.create(someVariable);`

Is there any way to modify this code to remove this alert from veracode ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform sanitization, validation or encoding with the req.body. It is a risk to blindly accept input that could potentially be tainted or coming from an untrusted source.

I assume that you are expecting input in a form of json so try escaping req.body using the [js-string-escape](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-string-escape) library:

```
var jsescape = require('js-string-escape');
const someVariable = jsescape(req.body);
await userModelName.create(someVariable);
```

Now Veracode might not recognize this third-party encoding library and will still fail your scan. You will have to propose this as a [mitigation](https://help.veracode.com/reader/DGHxSJy3Gn3gtuSIN2jkRQ/%7Ep4MSKOS8F8X8h0KwFTKoQ) step to your Security team.

Another alternative is to use Mongoose's [Validation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) feature, if you are expecting specific types of data:

```
const schema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

const someVariable = escape(req.body);
await userModelName.create(someVariable, schema);
```

Again, Veracode might not recognize this too but these are secure coding best practices.

Comment: Yeah, req.body has data in json form. So in mongoose create() function the data will be converted back to original form ?

Comment: i take my original answer back and modified my answer after realizing the output of the escape method isn't what you would expect